# Angular-Cloudinary not function in android5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloudinary

https://github.com/thenikso/angular-cloudinary
This is a plugin very easy for use, but I have problems when plugin run in android 5 + ionic with cordova, this problem not exist with version from android 4, the respon server is 400 with this {"error":{"message":"Missing required parameter - file"}}

Comment: The community wants to help you, and we are trying are best, but we can only understand questions that make sense. Try to format your question a bit differently after you check out StackOverflow's Help Center page on how to write a good question.

Comment: Couldn't understand which versions were problematic for you.
Basically, the error you're describing means that the file didn't send along with the upload request.

Can you verify that? or share more information regarding your work flow?